# How does MetaMask's TRANSACTION DATA work? How to interact with smart contracts by only using MetaMask?

Tags: solidity, transactions, metamask, contract-debugging, calldata

I have [this source code](https://capturetheether.com/challenges/warmup/nickname/)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

// Relevant part of the CaptureTheEther contract.
contract CaptureTheEther {
    mapping (address => bytes32) public nicknameOf;

    function setNickname(bytes32 nickname) public {
        nicknameOf[msg.sender] = nickname;
    }
}

// Challenge contract. You don't need to do anything with this; it just verifies
// that you set a nickname for yourself.
contract NicknameChallenge {
    CaptureTheEther cte = CaptureTheEther(msg.sender);
    address player;

    // Your address gets passed in as a constructor parameter.
    function NicknameChallenge(address _player) public {
        player = _player;
    }

    // Check that the first character is not null.
    function isComplete() public view returns (bool) {
        return cte.nicknameOf(player)[0] != 0;
    }
}
```

So is it possible to call `setNickname(bytes32 nickname)` with MetaMask using the Transaction Data field?

Further, if I have set the nickname - how can I call receive my nickname from `mapping (address => bytes32) public nicknameOf;` with MetaMask using the Transaction Data field?

Comment: I would highly recommend using [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org). I don't think MetaMask gives you any way to manually enter the data field, and you'd still want some tool to help figure out the right data to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it possible to call setNickname(bytes32 nickname) with MetaMask using the Transaction Data field?

You can do so by calling the function through its identifier and providing the according data.

Example: I want to call your function `setNickname(bytes32 nickname)` and set the name to "Teddy".

1. I insert the code into Remix IDE and deploy it in the JS EVM.
2. I convert Teddy to bytes, which is `5465646479`
3. I call the function with `"0x5465646479"`
4. I check the details of the transaction: [image: input]
5. ...and then click on the copy icon next to the `input` field.

This is the encoded data to paste into the `data`field in metamask when wishing to execute a contract function on a transaction.

Hint: You can find out [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-abi.html#encodefunctioncall) how to generate this `input data` with a script yourself ! :)

Answer (score -3):

MetaMask does not allow you to interact with smart contracts simply because smart contract functions/methods can be customised and varies from one contract to the other.